# how to solve Too many connections in mysql error?

Tags: php, mysql, database, scale

I have a php application. There is a lot of database operation and i do mysql_connect() to open connection. Do I have to close the connection manually?

Answer (score 2):

In general, after script execution the connections should close automatically. However in some cases (e.g. like yours) you have no other way but to do it manually (make `mysql_close($connection)` to be the last line of your script).

Alternatively, consider using `mysql_pconnect()` to have persistent connection, which doesn't close after script completion, and is (implicitly) reused on the next request.

Comment: I've had problems with PHP, MySQL and persistent connections few years ago - sometimes new connections were created even if there were *free* connections. Ultimately, this led to "Too many connections" error. I'm not sure though what was the cause of this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. But you do `mysql_connect()` many times. you can keep it in seperate file and include where ever needed.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the number of allowable connection in mysql settings should do the trick i guess. But before that make sure on each page you are only opening the mysql connection once. At the end of the script the connection should automatically be closed, so no you dont really have to close it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Use singleton to keep just one open connection on each page.

Comment: `mysql_connect()` and related functions keep track of opened connection, there's actually no need to use singleton. Even more - as far as I understand from documentation, if using `mysql_connect()` with the same parameters repeatedly, it reuses connection that is already opened.